# NTFS Freespace Issue: Disk Partitioning for Dual Boot System?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

Am about to partition the 1GB HDD on my existing Win8 installation, in preparation for installing Kubuntu 14.04.

**Issue is that the Win8 partition program is saying that about half of the remaining space is available for shrinking, yet its barely used (defrag done).**

Currently only ~ 40GB is being used on the NTFS partition for Win8. 
Yet the Win8 partition program will only allow me to shrink by 50% of the remaining (free) space. I have run DiskCleanup & the Defrag program that comes with Win8.

I will only be using Win8 for less than 5% of the time so its a complete waste of space giving 50% to Win8, when I want most of the disk space to be free for Kubuntu.

I could run the partition program during the Kubuntu installation, but read elsewhere that the repartitioning needs to be done via Win8 in order for Win8 to run under a dual boot?

Any suggestions please?

Cheers, many thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widnows build in programs wont help in shrinking the free space completely you can use "Mini Tool Partition Wizard Home Edition (freeware)"
http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html

how to resize partition see here http://www.partitionwizard.com/help/resize-partition.html

It will reboot and split c drive at boot without causing any problem to windows

Comment: Thanks Sudheer. Will give the suggested software a go.  Cheers Andy